# Testing for Stochastic Dominance - Mann Whitney with Unequal Variance

Tags: nonparametric, stochastic-processes, heteroscedasticity, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I've been looking for methods like Mann Whitney, but without homogeneity of variance. So far, I found that I suppose to test for stochastic dominance instead - i.e. modifying the null hypothesis. Could anybody refer books or any literature for me to study further? Thanks.

Comment: `like Mann Whitney, but without homogeneity of variance`. M-W tests for the stochastic dominance. It does not require homogeneity of variance.

Comment: There have been many, many good discussions of `Mann-Whitney` and its direct extension `Kruskal-Wallis` tests on this site. May I recommend you to search and browse though them first?

Comment: Would using the K-S test and then just plotting the CDF's be a reasonable test for this? Did you really mean to say M-W tests for stochastic dominance @ttnphns - I'm pretty sure you can construct situations in which the CDF's cross but M-W would still be significant.

Comment: That depends on how you define "stochastic dominance". That cdf curves cross does not preclude the non-0.5 probability that an observation randomly taken from one population is greater than such observation taken from the other population.

Comment: Moreover, M-W knows nothing about specifically variances. It is rank-based nonparametric test.

Comment: That is not [stochastic dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance) ttnphns! Stochastic dominance is a much more strict null. (The third order definition on the Wikipedia page is the *only* definition I have ever come across in statistical texts, so if you are thinking of another could you provide a source?)

Comment: @AndyW, I've once seen that wiki page. Perhaps you are correct, I won't object sharply. Or maybe that definition is too narrow? M-W test, when it was formulated, was - I suppose - not tied with that definition which, probably, appeared later. [I myself think that one is entitled to give/understand definitions of whatewer things as he likes it.] M-W tests for location difference, wherein I define "location" broader than "shift".

Comment: @AndyW I've several times seen  "Prob(A>B) > Prob(B>A)" described as "stochastic dominance" -- but it might not have been in the context of utility theory.

Comment: @AndyW Looking around, since "P(X>Y)=P(Y>X)" is often called "stochastic equality", it looks like some people have occasionally taken to calling "P(X>Y)>P(Y>X)" stochastic dominance. It appears not to be very widespread though. Mann and Whitney's original 1947 paper uses the term "stochastically larger", which would seem to be a better term.

Comment: However, the Mann-Whitney can be considered a test for the more strict case of stochastic dominance (as given at the link AndyW gave) -- one could accompany the minimal assumptions of the test with say the assumption of equality under the null and a dominance alternative -- as long as you can add those assumptions it will work fine. The test is somewhat sensitive to other kinds of differences, so if you can't make those additional assumptions it wouldn't be suitable.

Comment: @Glen_b P(A>B) > P(B>A) is NOT stochastic dominance, which is a well-known concept (one CDF always smaller than the other, and strictly so somewhere). This is a common misconception about Mann-Whitney. I don't know what you mean by a "dominance alternative" but the fact is unless you make strong assumptions about the shape of the distributions, M-W will not test correctly for dominance and will reject far too often. Andy W is correct in this regard, but not about using KS and then examining CDFs to test dominance. You may reject the null, but you should not conclude dominance this way.

Comment: Yes, this wasn't the correct term for the thing being described for the Mann-Whitney. I can point to some authors that use the term in exactly that way (which is where I first picked it up) but later learned that usage wasn't very widespread and conventionally it means something else. (I did fix at least one other post though.) ... I will see what  I can do to rephrase, though your comment is at least sufficient to make it clear there's an error.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me point out that Mann-Whitney **does not** test stochastic dominance. It tests the null hypothesis $P(X > Y) = P(X < Y)$. If $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ and $Y$ is 1 with probability 0.9 and 0 with probability 0.1, then the null is false but neither variable stochastically dominates the other. Stochastic dominance is a stronger condition.

There's plenty of literature on testing for dominance, though it is highly technical and requires some understanding of empirical processes. A Google Scholar search for "test stochastic dominance" will work. A famous reference is, e.g., [Barrett and Donald (2003), *Econometrica*, **71**, 1, "Consistent Tests for Stochastic Dominance"](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/1468-0262.00390).

Comment: (+1) But see [Glen_b's comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220703/testing-for-stochastic-dominance-mann-whitney-with-unequal-variance#comment417604_220703). The necessary assumptions can often be reasonable ones - more so than a location-shift alternative - & gross violations are apparent from examination of the empirical distribution functions.